# Number of possible Combo Passwords

Tags: combinatorics

I made a small demo for allowing key combinations in passwords:

http://combo-pw.tech

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19290613

Now I struggle to find out how many more possible passwords a "Combo Password" has compared to a normal password with the same number of key presses.

There are more. I can show this, but not calculate it properly since I apparently suck at combinatorics.

Keys: {0,1}
KeyPresses: 3

A normal password has 2^3 = 8 different combinations:
{000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111}

A combo password (e.g. "01,0" - the comma seperates the combinations) also has those 8 combinations: 
{"0,0,0","0,0,1","0,1,0","0,1,1","1,0,0","1,0,1","1,1,0","1,1,1"}

But there are more possibilities:
{"01,0", "01,1", "10,0", "10,1", "0,01", "0,10","1,01","1,10"}

Comment: I do not yet follow.  In your link it would appear as though "0,01" should be considered the same as "0,10" since the collection of digits in the second grouping are the same albeit in a different order.

Comment: For the remainder of this comment, I'll refer to collections of digits separated by commas as blocks, e.g. in 1,23,456 we have the block 1, the block 23, and the block 456.  Please clarify the following: How many commas are allowed in total?  If we rearrange the numbers inside of a block does that count as different?  (is 1,23,456 the same as 1,32,465?)  If we rearrange blocks themselves does that count as different?  (is 1,23,456 the same as 456,1,23?)  Can a character be repeated inside of a block?  (is 1,11 an allowable password?)  Can blocks repeat? (is 1,23,23 an allowable password?)

Comment: There are two different behaviours of the password check, toggled with the checkSequence flag via the checkbox. When false "0,01" = "0,10", when true "0,01" != "0,10".

Comment: Assuming then order of blocks matters, order within blocks matter, any number of commas may be used, characters may be repeated inside of a block, and blocks can repeat with $k$ characters available and a "password length" (ignoring commas) of $n$ you would have $k^n\times 2^{n-1}$ possible passwords.  That shouldn't be surprising though if you interpret the password as a length $2n-1$ string where every even position is either filled by the empty character or by the comma.  If digits may not repeat within a block then things get messy.

Comment: The amount of allowed commas (or better say key combinations) is 1 to ammount of keypresses. But if there are not enough keys like in my questions example where there are more keys pressed (3)  than keys available (2) the minimum is higher.
"1,23,456 " can never equal "456,1,23" and characters can not be repeated inside a of a block. Blocks can repeat.

Comment: Assuming digits cannot repeat within a block... the easiest approach I can think of for calculating would be the use of generating functions.  With $k$ characters and a password of length $n$ (*not counting commas*), the total number of possibilities would be the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i}x^i)^n$ in the case that order within a block doesn't matter and the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^k k\frac{i}{~}x^i)^n$ in the case that order within a block does matter (here $k\frac{i}{~}=\frac{k!}{(k-i)!}$is falling factorial)

Comment: As for the "usefulness" of this "new password style" I am skeptical.  Not only is it more frustrating to use and harder to implement than traditional passwords, it really isn't that different than just including the comma characters as a part of a traditional password in the first place, which if you were to have the ability to do so you could have used a character other than the comma (or empty character) in its place to give far more possibilities.  It doesn't really aid in the memorization of passwords either as memorizing blocks works just as well in traditional passwords.

Comment: Thanks for your help and feedback! I will need some time to wrap my head around this and to implement this as functions.
I don't quite get what you mean with the commas. They are only a visual divider for key combinations. Using another character in its place would not change the number of possibilities in any way.

Comment: Internally I use key codes in an array for a single key combination. Multiple of these combinations form a password. The commas get added only for human readable output.